# Similarity between two conditional discrete distribution

Tags: correlation, feature-engineering, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Having data of X:Y where X is a categorical feature and Y is multiclass label (i.e Sweet:Apple , Red: Apple, Sweet:Orange, Sugary: Banana )

I've created for each X the conditional frequency/ distribution P(Y|X)  so for each unique X I have a vector of 100 values of Y's with a count of occurrences :

X1 : [1,0,0,0,23,1,0,3,...]
X2 : [5,0,1,0,59,0,0,7,...]

at the moment to check if two Xi, Xj are correlated I am using Pearson correlation over the vectors. I would like to try using kl divergence but it seems like an issue because of the many zero values I have.

What I'm aiming to do is to find correlated features that might be the same, such as "sweet" and Sugary which will have a similar distribution.  (it's an example so using synonyms won't help)

Any idea of how to incorporate information base metric here? or other useful ideas